# backward-kill-word ignores whitespaces, is there another friendlier version?

Tags: deletion

Emac's `backward-kill-word` tends to delete more than I want.
E.g when I press delete multiple times on this:

```
(key-chord "qf" 'helm-org-in-buffer-headings)   ;heading search. |
```

I get:

```
1. (key-chord "qf" 'helm-org-in-buffer-headings)   ;heading|
2. (key-chord "qf" 'helm-org-in-buffer-headings)   ;|
3. (key-chord "qf" 'helm-org-in-buffer-|   <<< too much deletion.
```

I expected this in the 3rd step:

```
3. (key-chord "qf" 'helm-org-in-buffer-headings)|
```

I want to know:
- Is there a philosophy behind deleting more than what's wanted?
- Can I make emac's backward-delete-word more friendly? I.e, remove white spaces but don't kill off 'too' much?

**EDIT** 
I don't really know 'what' I want. Maybe make it more like other delet functions like in google-keep or other text editing applications.

**edit2**
In the mean time, lawlist fixed up his custom function which works rather well: [enter link description here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10644/backward-kill-word-ignores-whitespaces-is-there-another-friendlier-version)

Comment: This risks being closed as unclear. You do not specify what behavior you want. *Specify.* `backward-kill-word` does what it is intended to do. You can define another command to do "what's wanted" and not "kill off 'too' much". But if you want help with that then you might consider actually specifying the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Here is a link to my own delete-word function, which you may be interested modifying to suit your needs:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20456861/2112489  It is not designed to store the deletion into the kill-ring, so I call it delete rather than kill.  It has nothing to do with helm or key cord.  The behavior (in my opinion) approximates what various word processors have done over the years.

Comment: @lawlist  yah, this is more or less what I was looking for, except that I found the function there doesn't wrap around and doesn't start deleting things if there are trailing white spaces?

Comment: Emacs philosophy is to always stay one step ahead of the user.So you just don't know yet.

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev is there anything you don't like about the solution I provided?

Comment: A new package [`syntax-subword`](https://bitbucket.org/jpkotta/syntax-subword/src) just got added to Melpa that might resolve this question.

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour of `backward-kill-word` depends on the definition of a "word" in the current mode.  You can either change this definition and risk breaking stuff or you could modify `kill-word`.

`backward-kill-word` is just `kill-word` with a negative argument; `kill-word` is `kill-region` over the region spanned by point and the position after running `(forward-word arg)`.  Replacing `forward-word` temporarily should do the trick.

Here I'm temporarily replacing `forward-word` with `forward-same-syntax` to achieve the desired effect in `backward-kill-word` (and `kill-word` because I like things to be consistent):

```
(defun my/kill-word-advice (orig-fun &rest args)
  "Replace forward-word with forward-same-syntax."
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'forward-word) #'forward-same-syntax))
    (apply orig-fun args)))
(advice-add 'kill-word :around #'my/kill-word-advice)
```

Now the behaviour is this:

```
1. (key-chord "qf" 'helm-org-in-buffer-headings)   ;heading|
2. (key-chord "qf" 'helm-org-in-buffer-headings)   ;|
3. (key-chord "qf" 'helm-org-in-buffer-headings)   |
4. (key-chord "qf" 'helm-org-in-buffer-headings)|
5. (key-chord "qf" 'helm-org-in-buffer-headings|
5. (key-chord "qf" 'helm-org-in-buffer-|
```

Comment: Hello, I tried the above, but when I run backwards kill word, I still get the old behaviour. I'm on Emacs 25.4 with newest org-mode..

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev I saw you mention 25.4 somewhere else too. Do you mean 24.5? Or 24.4?

Comment: Hmm,  I think I got muddled up. I meant 25.0.50.4. And maybe a month ago I used 25.0.50.3, but now I updated.

Comment: @rekado I can’t get this to work in 24.5.1. Any idea? Executing the `advice-add` sexp returns `nil`, is that expected?

Comment: It may very well be that you first have to eval the original definition of `kill-word` before the advice is applied :(  I don't know why that is.  Will ask on the mailing list.